# What in my CruiseControl.NET configuration is causing this exception?

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

In attempting to set up a build for a demo project I am working on, I received the following exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\1bea7440-959c-4dd4-89ad-05dcd00e369c\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll'

**Question**: What don't I have configured correctly?

Below is my task block from my ccnet.config file:

```
<tasks>
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>C:\CCWorkingDirectory\DemoApplication</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>DemoApplication.sln</projectFile>
        <!--<buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /v:quiet
            /p:Configuration=Debug
            /p:ReferencePath="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.7\bin"
        </buildArgs>-->
        <targets>ReBuild</targets >
        <timeout>600</timeout >
        <!--<logger>c:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCNet.dll</logger >-->
    </msbuild>
</tasks>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll in the working directory of your application.

So you need to put ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll in C:\CCWorkingDirectory\DemoApplication

Here's a link about the [MSBuild](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/MsBuild+Task) tag.

You could alternatively include it in the logger tag like so:

```
<logger>
    C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\
        ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll
</logger>
```

Comment: Really?  Can I not just tell CCNet where to find that DLL?

Comment: You could alternatively fully qualify it in your logger tag.  I'll update my question to reflect.